# PHP check if date is between first and last day of current month

Tags: php, date

Checking a $datetest array to find out if set dates are between the first and last day of current month. Output is wrong. dates, such as, '11-08-2014', '11-8-2014', are right and wrong in the output.

```
//get First day of Month
//get Last day of Month

$first_day_of_month = date('m-01-Y');

$last_day_of_month = date('m-t-Y');

echo "First Day of Month: ";
echo $first_day_of_month;

echo "<br />";

echo "Last Day of Month: ";
echo $last_day_of_month;

$datetest = array('11-30-2014', '11-31-2014', '11-08-2014', '11-8-2014', '11-9-2014', '11-11-2014', '11-24-2014', '11-1-2014', '10-30-2014', '12-1-2014', '11-1-1997');

echo "<br /><br />";

foreach ($datetest as $datetest) {  
if (($datetest >= $first_day_of_month) && ($datetest <= $last_day_of_month)){

    echo "$datetest :";
    echo " Is in Month!";
    echo "<br />";

} else {
    echo "$datetest :";
    echo "Not in Month!";
    echo "<br />";
}
}
```

Outputs:
First Day of Month: 11-01-2014
Last Day of Month: 11-30-2014

11-30-2014 : Is in Month!

11-31-2014 :Not in Month!

11-08-2014 : Is in Month!

11-8-2014 :Not in Month!    X

11-9-2014 :Not in Month!    X

11-11-2014 : Is in Month!

11-24-2014 : Is in Month!

11-1-2014 : Is in Month!

10-30-2014 :Not in Month!

12-1-2014 :Not in Month!

11-1-1997 : Is in Month!    X

Comment: `t` *"Number of days in the given month  28 through 31"* as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php I think you meant to use `d` - unless that's what you really want to use?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `t` would be correct when looking for the last day in the month as `d` would be the current day.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks Jonathan; I wasn't entirely sure. *I stand corrected*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already @mark91 has told you, the comparison you are doing right now is wrong since you are practically comparing `string`s against `string` and not actual dates:

The **best** (if possible) way to fix your problem would be to first change your date format to `YYYY-mm-dd` and then use `strtotime()` before comparing the values.

If changing the values is not an option you could use a combination of `mktime` to "build" your dates (as numbers) and `explode()` to convert "your" format to proper time format as in the sample code i tried for you

[Test Date Comparisons](http://3v4l.org/inIoX)

Note I am building the start and end dates using `mktime()` with a `1` (first day) and a `date('n')` (number of days in month = equal to last day of month). For more info check [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

The script inside the loop, breaks (`explode`) up the poorly formatted date into an array, and then `mktime()` generates the date back into a numeric date representation (unix timestamp) which can be used for easy and **correct** comparison of the values.

---

### Important Parts:

Build `first` and `last` dates using:

```
$first_day_of_month = mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),1,date('Y')); 
$last_day_of_month = mktime(23,59,59,date('n'),date('t'),date('Y'));
```

Split and build the date for comparison:

```
$split_date = explode("-",$datetest); 
$comp_date = mktime(0,0,0,$split_date[0],$split_date[1],$split_date[2]);
```

Compare the unix timestamps instead of the strings:

```
if (($comp_date >= $first_day_of_month) && ($comp_date <= $last_day_of_month)){
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are not comparing dates, but strings representing them. If you want to do so, you have to re-format your dates (in order to have formats like `YYYY-mm-dd`) or, better, you just need to convert them in timestamps and compare them (you can do this with `mktime`).

Answer (score 3):

```
$first_day_of_month = strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));
$last_day_of_month = strtotime(date('Y-m-t 23:59:59'));

echo "First Day of Month: ";
echo $first_day_of_month;

echo "<br />";

echo "Last Day of Month: ";
echo $last_day_of_month;

$datetests = array('2014-11-30', '2014-11-31', '2014-11-08');
echo "<br /><br />";

foreach ($datetests as $datetest) {  
if ((strtotime($datetest) >= $first_day_of_month) && (strtotime($datetest) <= $last_day_of_month)){

    echo "$datetest :";
    echo " Is in Month!";
    echo "<br />";

} else {
    echo "$datetest :";
    echo "Not in Month!";
    echo "<br />";
}
}
```

Comment: This works if the dates are in the format of `Y-m-d` but fails in the format they are currently in.

Comment: I agree, but the format the dates are in should be trivial to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the comparison by comparing with the month of the year, then perform a valid day check.
If you won't have issues like `32-08-2014` or `0-08-2014`, you can leave the day check.

```
 public function isWithinCurrentMonth($date)
 {
    $current_month = date('Y-m');
    $transaction_date_month = date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
    $transaction_day = $date('d', strtotime($date));
    $last_day = $date('t');

    return $current_month == $transaction_date_month
         // day validity check
        && intval($transaction_day) > 0
        && intval($transaction_day) <= intval($last_day);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because date() returns a string. Convert the string to an int using ***intval()***

```
// gets the year (as an integer)
$date = intval(date('Y'));
```

Integer comparisons are much easier than string comparsions.